# Mathematical Induction for: $ \binom{-1/2}{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_{n-k} \binom{-1/2}{k-1}=0 $

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that there is only one possible choice for all coefficients $a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1}\neq0$, $\forall n\geq1$, such that:
$$
\binom{-1/2}{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_{n-k} \binom{-1/2}{k-1}=0
$$
If $n=2$, the relationship is easily demonstrated.
I am not sure how to continue. Can someone show me how?

Thanks

Comment: Question: Do you actually want to show there is only one infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ such that, for each $n\ge 1,$ the identity holds? Otherwise for $n=3$ the identity is $3/8+a_2-(1/2)a_1=0$ with a one parameter family of solutions $(a_1,a_2).$

Comment: Mark: I interpreted it as in my above comment in the answer given below. Let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: I have not explained well, sorry. For example, if $n = 2$ we have:$\binom{-1/2}{1} +a_{1} \binom{-1/2}{0}=0$. From this equation we can find the unknown quantity $a_1$. Later, we substitute the value obtained in equation: $\binom{-1/2}{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_{n-k} \binom{-1/2}{k-1}=0$ and so on for $a_2,a_3...$.

Comment: Mark: Your question was whether there was only one choice for the sequence of $a_k$, which my answer shows, and your comment just above seems to mean that you already knew that. Is your question really about what exactly are the values of the numbers $a_k$, i.e. a formula in terms of $k$? That would be more difficult, to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E_n$ denote your equation $$\binom{-1/2}{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_{n-k} \binom{-1/2}{k-1}=0
$$
Then $a_{n-1}$ occurs first in equation $E_n$ (and not in the preceeding formulas). So you can use equation $E_n$ to determine the value of $a_{n-1}$, assuming previous values of $a_k$ for $k<n-1$ have been found. [Starting value $a_1=-1/2$.]

Since each new equation can be viewed as a recursive way to find $a_{n-1}$ in terms of previous $a_k$, it shows there is only one such sequence, and how to find it (though maybe a mess).